# Named Pages: Footer on last page only

Tags: visualforce, css, html

I am attempting to place a footer image in the bottom-right section of the last page of the Visualforce PDF only. I have found a solution that use named pages, however I cannot seem to get the following code to work. It doesn't seem to read the named page's properties at all.

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" showHeader="false" applyhtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
   <html>
      <head>
          <style type="text/css" media="print">
            @page { margin: 0in;}
            @page last {
                margin-bottom: 10%;
                @bottom-right {
                    content: "hi"
                }
            }
            body, html {
              height:100%; 
              margin: 0 !important; 
              padding: 0 !important;
            }
            .lastPage {
                 page: last
            }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div>I can span multiple pages</div>
        <div class="lastPage"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Is there something that I am missing? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think "page:last" is correct.  I found the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136333/css-paged-media-last-page-selector
which appears to be a solution for what you are trying to do.

Excerpt of the CSS in that solution (edited to match your class name):

```
.lastPage {
    page: last_page;
    page-break-before: always; /* Use if your last page is blank, else omit. */
}

@page {
   @bottom-right {
       content: "Please turn over";
    }
}

@page lastPage {
    @bottom-right {
        content: none;
    }
}
```